# jQuery Datatables Server-side processing empty column with custom values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm planning to use datatables to retrieve all my user data from a mysql table and display them . I'm using their server-side processing code to retrieve all data . I've a requirement where certain additional columns that require custom value to be inserted .

```
$('#data').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "userlist.php"
} );
```

In server side processing,

```
$aColumns = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
```

Actual columns to be displayed,

```
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
<th>col3</th>
<th>col4</th>
```

where col4 contains an example code like ,

```
<a href='del.php?userid=col1value></a>
```

How can i accomplish this ?

Refer : http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is send the fourth column as HTML tag, and it will work for example while returning the value from serverside

```
$aColumns = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', "<a href='del.php?userid=col1value>sometext</a>");
```

and it will work :).

P.S: you can return anything from server side, it can be HTML tags or a string, datatables will place the value inside of your column without any problem.

Comment: Hi, the array in acolums denote column name in mysql so i think i cannot write html code there.

Comment: I ended up uisng mDataProp. Thanks for your help.